# How to redirect google sign in button

Tags: java, android

After adding the Google sign in button, connected with Firebase of course, where do i add the redirect after the user signs in to a new activity?

tried adding it in the same function as the button, no errors or anything, the app just crashes

here's the main java code:

```
package com.example.firebase.firebaseyoutube;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private static String TAG = "MAIN_ACTIVITY";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user != null)
                Log.d("AUTH", "user logged in: " + user.getEmail());
            else
                Log.d("AUTH", "user logged out.");
        }
    };

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(mAuthListener != null)
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

        if(result.isSuccess()){
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        }
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "Google Login Failed");

    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct){
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d("AUTH", "signInWithCredential:oncomplete: " + task.isSuccessful());
                }
            });
}

private void signIn(){
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

private void signOut(){
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed.");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;
        case R.id.sign_out_button:
            signOut();
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, that's an error! Add the logcat

Comment: i already removed it, but the thing i where do i add the function? within the sign in function? or just create another one?

Comment: `onActivityResult` is what happens after you click the button